# How to add a border line without shadow effect in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

[image: where tree view border is not with single line but with shadow effect]

the above tree view is looking with shadow effect on top left and left. I need a single thick line .

my xaml is

```
       Margin="0,0,0,2"  BorderBrush="Black"  BorderThickness="1"
```

I need a single line but not a shodow. Can you please help me how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this to get rid of treeview border and apply your own border:

```
 <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
        <TreeView BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"

        </TreeView>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to create simple `Template` for your `TreeView` like so:

```
<TreeView BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="Beige">
   <TreeView.Template>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
         <Border 
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
            <ScrollViewer>
               <ItemsPresenter/>
            </ScrollViewer>
         </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
   </TreeView.Template>
</TreeView>
```